# pyarrow not effective at speeding up toPandas() on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I am using `python 3.7`, `pyspark 2.4.5`, `pyarrow 1.0.1`, `pandas 0.25.1` in Windows, with the environment variable `ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1` set

I am trying to convert a spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe, using pyarrow to speed up the conversion.

The code that I ran:

```
%time test_pd = test.toPandas() #No pyarrow
Wall time: 19.9 s
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
%time test_pd = test.toPandas() #pyarrow enabled
Wall time: 17.9 s
```

It almost seems like they are running at similar time, with enabling pyarrow only speed up two seconds.

Going on to test if pyarrow is actually running or not, I try to recreate the example as mentioned in the blog: https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/07/26/spark-arrow/

Here is the code that I ran:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
df = spark.range(1 << 22).toDF("id").withColumn("x", rand())
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- x: double (nullable = false)

%time pdf = df.toPandas() #No pyarrow
Wall time: 23.7 s
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
%time pdf = df.toPandas() #pyarrow enabled
Wall time: 1.32 s
```

So it seems pyarrow is massive speeding up `df` here, but for my dataset the effect is minimal?? My `test` dataframe here has 528492 row x 6 columns, but then `pdf` here also contains 4194304 rows × 2 columns, which has similar number of elements in total compare to my dataset.

Does anyone understand what is going on? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the test dataframe already cached/computed?  i.e. have you isolated that the time spent is actually in serialization?